# Calculate porcentage of occurrence between 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, percentage

A have a table in postgresql like this:

| elem1 | elem2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| A | A |
| A | B |
| A | C |
| B | D |
| B | C |
| C | E |

And I wish to do do a query that get all pairs and its relative percentage of elem2 that matches elem 1. The output would be like this:

| elem1 | elem2 | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | 0.5 |
| A | B | 0.25 |
| A | C | 0.25 |
| B | D | 0.5 |
| B | C | 0.5 |
| C | E | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to independently count `elem1` and `(elem1,elem2)`. You can get this with a CTE for each. Then JOIN them on `elem1` and compute the percentage of `elem1` to `elem2`. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/tC02xC1F))

```
with e1(elem1, c1) as   
       ( select elem1, count(*) 
           from test 
          group by elem1 
       )  
   , e2(elem1,elem2,c2) as  
       ( select elem1, elem2, count(*) 
           from test 
          group by elem1, elem2
       ) 
select e2.elem1, e2.elem2, round((1.0 * c2)/c1,2) percentage
  from e1 
  join e2 on (e2.elem1 = e1.elem1)
 order by e2.elem1, e2.elem2;
```